# How to add ellipsis with count of remaining item using angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can we achieve the ellipsis with the count of element that is not included in the area.

Example

> I have array of name  Apple,Mango,Straw,Litchi,Orange,Grapes

My Container is say 100px wide which can carry only few name depending on the width.

Result should come as

> Apple,Mango,Straw... +3 more

or

> Apple,Mango... + 4 more if(width is less)

How to Achieve this thing with angular.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ellipsisCreator = function(array) {
                    var arraySize = [],
                        size = 0,
                        stopCounter = 0;
                        scope.toolTiptext = null;
                        scope.visibleText = null;
                        scope.remaining = 0;
                        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                            var e=document.createElement('span');
                                document.body.appendChild(e);
                                e.style.fontSize = scope.fontsize+'px';
                                e.setAttribute("class", "posAbs");
                                e.innerHTML = array[i];
                                arraySize.push(e.offsetWidth+5);
                                e.remove();
                                if(size + arraySize[i] >=  scope.length){
                                    stopCounter = i-1;
                                    break;
                                }else{
                                    size = size + arraySize[i];
                                    stopCounter = i;
                                }
                        }
                        scope.visibleText = array.slice(0,stopCounter+1).join(', ');
                        if(stopCounter<array.length-1){
                            scope.toolTiptext = array.slice(stopCounter+1,array.length).join(', ');
                            scope.remaining = (array.length-1) - stopCounter;
                        }
                };
```